# How to show material design icons in storybook for vue

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, storybook

I'm using storybook for vue & vuetify.

It's useful but can't see material design icons as `v-icons`.

how to show icons in storybook?

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is that the material design icon stylesheet is not being downloaded by Storybook, you may be able to put a `preview-head.html` file in your `.storybook` directory.

Once I did so, I was able to put the following contents, and after that, my material icons displayed correctly.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
```

I got this from the "Adding Webfonts" section from this page of the Storybook docs. https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/styling-and-css

*Note - I'm using Svelte, not Vue, and the documentation is technically for React. I'm not sure if there's a different project structure for Vue. Since it's the same for React and Svelte though, I assume it's common to all Storybook projects.

Comment: Link to an example of preview-head.html https://storybook.js.org/docs/configure/story-rendering